# I need to add another level of protection on the JWT payload

Tags: security, jwt, token

Bearer token can be decoded into plain text. 
I need to add another level of protection on the JWT payload.
I have a REST API service that implements JWT bearer token based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

[JSON Web Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) (JWT) is a open standard that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object.

JWT is just a *generic name* for the following types of token:

- [JSON Web Signature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) (JWS): The payload is *encoded* and signed so the *integrity* of the claims can be verified.
- [JSON Web Encryption](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) (JWE): They payload is *encrypted* so the claims are *hidden* from other parties.

[image: JWT, JWS and JWE]
<sup>The image was extracted from this [page](https://medium.facilelogin.com/jwt-jws-and-jwe-for-not-so-dummies-b63310d201a3).</sup>

If you want to hide the claims from other parties, you are looking for JWE.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I use both passport and JWT?
And encrypting JWT is good way for security?

Comment: You can also create nested tokens i.e. the JWT is signed then encrypted (in this order)